# Save individual html-files in Httrack

Tags: pdf, html, mirroring, httrack

I use Httrack to save a web page.

Normally I add a URL and mirror the website with all its subpages until I limit the depth or have them all. This results in an index.html file that I can open and call up the individual pages as I would online.

Now, however, I need each of these subpages as individual html files. If I do this with the "Get separated files" function, the process stops after the main page, which is linked in the programm. It would be too much work to call up each URL of each subpage individually to paste it into the list.

Is there a possibility?
I would like to convert each of these HTML files into a PDF eventually, but it would be nice to get to the individual files in the first place.

Comment: Httrack will download the HTML files, just as they are on the website. Can't you for that website just display each page in the browser without passing through the index.html file?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are way too much pages to do that. That's why I downloaded HTTrack.

Comment: I mean, after downloading the files, they should be locally available for viewing from the local disk. The question is if they can be used separately without passing through index.html

Comment: Oh, wow, now that you mention it ... Yes, there is such a folder!
But it's all completely unsorted and the names are completely different. How am I ever supposed to get through it?

Comment: Take one file as an example and try to make the connection between the file-name and the title information inside the HTML header.

Comment: How do I do this exactly? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Sorry, I can only point out directions, not follow through every step. Examine the file in a text editor and try to reach some conclusions.